# Eclipse doesn't import dropbox egg

Tags: python, django, eclipse, dropbox, egg

Hello and excuse me for my English.

I have problems with importing dropbox.egg in my django project, I am using Eclipse as IDE on Windows 7. I installed dropbox.egg with easy_install on my c:\Python27. In System libraries of my project I've the dropbox.egg as like this:

**'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dropbox-1.5.1-py2.7.egg'**

I have also tried to import dropbox.egg as external libs but I didn't have success.

My sys.path produced this output:

```
['C:\\Users\\Blackat\\Documents\\workspace\\Gestionale', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-    packages\\oauth-1.0.1-py2.7.egg', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\dropbox-1.5.1-py2.7.egg', 
'C:\\Users\\Blackat\\Documents\\workspace\\Gestionale', 'C:\\Python27', 
'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-
packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL']
```

This is the error, which is printed in Eclipse console:

```
from dropbox import client,session
File "C:\Users\Blackat\Documents\workspace\Gestionale\edicola\dropbox.py", 
line 14, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name session**
```

and this is the error, which is displayed on django page

```
cannot import name session
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name session
Exception Location: C:\Users\Blackat\Documents\workspace\Gestionale\edicola\pippo.py in     
<module>, line 6
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Blackat\\Documents\\workspace\\Gestionale',
'C:\\Users\\Blackat\\Documents\\workspace\\Gestionale',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\oauth-1.0.1-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\dropbox-1.5.1-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\Python27',
'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python27\\lib',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
'dropbox_python_sdk-1.5.1-py2.7.egg']
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the actual code that raises these errors? Did you write `import dropbox.egg` instead of just `import dropbox`?

Comment: Also, why have you added things in your `site-packages` to your `sys.path`? Are you installing into the wrong `site-packages`? Or have you so broken your installation that the correct `site-packages` doesn't work? Or did someone tell you to do this for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a file called `dropbox.py` as part of your project? If so, I suspect that's what's being imported instead of the actual Dropbox package. Try renaming `dropbox.py` to something else.